# My webpack configuration display a listing directory instead of my dev app page

Tags: wordpress, webpack, wordpress-theming, webpack-dev-server

I search for a answer at my problem.

When i start my command "npm run watch" in my wordpress theme project. My webpack-dev-server start but i've only a browser page on a listing directory.

[screen of the browser page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOR34.png)

My webpack.config.js :

```
const path = require('path'),
removeEmptyScriptsPlugin = require('webpack-remove-empty-scripts'),
webpackConfig = require('@wordpress/scripts/config/webpack.config');

// Extend the @wordpress webpack config and add the entry points.
module.exports = {
    ...webpackConfig,
    ...{
        mode: 'production',
        devServer: {
            static: {
                directory: path.join(__dirname, '/'),
            },
            client: {
                overlay: false,
            },
            hot: true,
            compress: true,
            devMiddleware: {
                writeToDisk: true,
            },
        },
        context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets'),
        entry: ['./main.js', './main.scss'],
        // jQuery support
        /*externals: {
            jquery: "jQuery",
        },*/
        plugins: [
            ...webpackConfig.plugins,
            /*new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                $: "jquery",
                jQuery: "jquery",
                "window.jQuery": "jquery",
            }),*/
            new removeEmptyScriptsPlugin({
                stage: removeEmptyScriptsPlugin.STAGE_AFTER_PROCESS_PLUGINS,
            }),
        ],
    },
};
```

the structure of my wordpress :

`project/app/public/standard-wordpress-files-structure/wp-content/themes/theme`

And the structure of the theme :

[tree structure of my theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/furoN.png)

Any idea what going on and how to fix it ?

I tried to add a publicPath but nothing have change.

change the `directory: path.join(__dirname, 'assets'),` by `directory: path.join(__dirname, '/'),`

I test 2 local dev environnement:

- first, a [phpmonitor](https://phpmon.app/) (valet)
- A wordpress dev env with [Local](https://localwp.com/)

No differences